# Check if mysql insert datetime is between the datetimes in table already

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert an appointment in a mysql database, but I want to check whether there is already an appointment in the diary for that time.  In the database there is a datetime field holding the start time in Y-m-d H:i:s format and another with the end time.

I need to check whether the start time or end time of the appointment that I am inserting falls between an existing entries start or end time.

This is how I am thinking of it but don't know the correct syntax:

```
   "SELECT `id` 
   FROM `events` 
   WHERE ('$start-time-of-appt-to-be-inserted' BETWEEN `a-time-in-the-start-column` OR `a-time-in-the-end-column`)
   OR ('$end-time-of-appt-to-be-inserted' BETWEEN `a-time-in-the-start-column` OR `a-time-in-the-end-column`)"
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm  `$query="select * from table where date_column between "date1" and "date2";`